# Just installed ubuntu trying to install DWA-182 wireless usb adapter driver please help

Tags: wireless

pardon me but I recently installed Ubuntu 18.4 LTS on my Laptop Asus Vivobook Model X540BA-RB94 which I just found out it doesn't have an Ethernet controller. Now I was able to get a wireless USB stick. D-LINK DWA-182 Version C I couldn't find drivers for the onboard wireless so I got wireless stick. . I downloaded the driver from the site for linux for D-LINK DWA-182 version C

My question is how do I install the driver ? It's on a USB stick.

The name of file as a Zip DWA-182_REVC_DRIVER+_4.3.2_LINUX.ZIP

Extracted File Name: RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411

When I access the extracted file and go to the driver I have rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.2_11100.20140411.tar.gz

Kindly guide me on how to install this ?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `lsusb` and also: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

https://github.com/chaotaklon/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

ubuntu 19 killed my wifi adapter

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the H/W Version. It will be written on the sticker on the dongle.
2. Go to [DLink product support page](https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=dwa-182) and select the hardware version of the driver applicable to you. Download the driver for Linux.

3. Extract the zip file. Navigate to 'driver' folder.
4. Extract the tar.gz file. In the new folder that is now created (which contains files like 'clean', 'Makefile' etc), open a new terminal.
5. In the terminal type:

> sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

6. After the installation is complete type:

> make

7. Now:

> sudo make install

8. Restart the computer.

Hopefully DLink DWA-182 is now detected by the system and wifi options are available.